# How to fetch values from cursor into variables?

Tags: oracle

I have problems fetching values from cursor into variables:

```
create or replace 
procedure projectinfo(num clubs.clubid%type) 
as
--identify variables
p_cln clubs.clubname%type;
p_projn projects.projectname%type;
p_projnum number;
p_taskn tasks.taskname%type;
p_tasknum number;

cursor cur is 
select c.clubname, p.projectname, t.taskname 
from clubs c join projects p on  c.clubid=p.clubid
join tasks t on t.projectid=p.projectid
where c.clubid=num;
--I have checked the above cursor and it's worked fine!!!
begin
p_projnum:=0;
p_tasknum:=0;

open cur;

loop

fetch cur into p_cln,p_projn, p_taskn;
dbms_output.put_line(p_cln|| ' ' ||p_projn|| ' ' || p_taskn);
-- the above command does not print variable values!!!
exit when cur%notfound;

p_projnum:=p_projnum+1;

dbms_output.put_line(' ************************ ');
dbms_output.put_line(' club name : ' ||p_cln);
dbms_output.put_line( ' project ' ||p_projnum|| ' ' || p_projn);

loop   
p_tasknum:=p_tasknum+1;
dbms_output.put_line('Task: ' ||p_tasknum|| ' '  || p_taskn);

fetch cur into p_cln,p_projn, p_taskn;
exit when cur%notfound;
end loop;
end loop;
close cur;
end projectinfo;
```

I have checked my cursor and itdoes contain all values that I need. My programm compiles FINE but does not print any output!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What tool are you using to run your procedure?  By default, most tools will not allocate a buffer for `dbms_output` to write to and will not display anything written to `dbms_output`.  That's why you'd never depend on `dbms_output` for any real code.

If you are using SQL*Plus, you need to enable `serveroutput` before executing your procedure

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> exec projectinfo( <<some number>> );
```

If you are using a GUI, the GUI will almost certainly have a way to enable `dbms_output`.  But that will be very different for different applications.  In SQL Developer, for example, you'd need to ensure that the `DBMS Output` window is visible, click the green "plus sign" icon, and choose your connection to enable `dbms_output`.